# Result of concatenation

Tags: single-word-requests

The word *sum* can be used to mean the result of addition of a two or more numbers, while *difference* denotes the result of subtraction etc. Is there a single word that denotes the result of concatenation of two text strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A/the concatenation https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concatenation

**concatenation (n.) 1 : a group of things linked together or occurring together in a way that produces a particular result or effect**

> an unusual concatenation of circumstances George McGovern was the beneficiary, in 1972, of a unique concatenation of party reform and political accident.— Garry Wills
>
> 2 : the act of concatenating things or the state of being concatenated: union in a linked series
>
> Mannering by this time was aware that one thought linked strangely on to another in the concatenation of worthy Mr. Bertram's ideas.— Walter Scott